# UE5 Multi-User editor does not save C++ classes

Tags: plugins, unreal-engine5

I am working on Unreal Engine project with a friend, we are using the Multi-User editor plugin + Hamachi to work on the same project at the same time, everything works fine except for the C++ Classes, for some reason the .cpp and .h files are not getting replicated to my friend computer and vice versa.

I know I can use github for this, but I prefer using the Multi-User plugin.

We each tried to create a C++ class and see if the other can see it, we also tried to create a blueprint with the C++ class, we could see each other blueprints but the blueprint didn't work because it could not find the source code.